# How to Sum all the characters inserted into textbox on page load event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have the following given parameters:

```
Alphabet   Provided Value

S           2
U           3
M           5
```

I have textbox with the default text SUM, and a label to display result of the SUM, i want to sum all the alphabets inserted in textbox like S+U+M if s=2, U=3 and M=5 and the Result displayed in the Label as output is 10

I want to write the program for doing that...in VB.NET

**EDIT:**

```
Dim text = textbox1.text 
Dim sum = 0 
For Each c As Char In text 
    sum += c - 64 
Next
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Stack Overflow isn't a place to have others write your code for you.

Comment: Dim text = textbox1.text
Dim sum = 0
For Each c As Char In text
 sum += c - 64
Next

Comment: Are you getting an error when you run this?

Comment: I have an error...- operator is not used with char or Integer datatype

Comment: Same error I got - so the question now is why are you trying to subtract 64 from the Char?  What do you expect that to give you?

Comment: I try this code also ....without substract 64 still its not working

Comment: Not working how?  It's not giving you 10?  That's because ASCII starts at 65 for A, and goes to 90 for Z.  The numbers you have in your post appear to be random, which is why I asked how are the numeric values assigned for the letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you're trying to subtract 64 from a Char - when I try your code, I get a '-' operator is not defined for types 'Char' and 'Integer'.

Try using `Asc` to get the ASCII value:

```
Dim text As String = textbox1.Text
Dim sum As Integer = 0

For Each c As Char in text
    sum += Asc(c) - 64
Next
```

However, that will give you 53 for SUM, not 10.  What system are you using for determining the numeric value of a given letter?  The code you posted indicates your substracting 64 - if not for ASCII, then what is the number 64 for?

**Edit**

Assuming that you have predefined numeric values for each letter, I would put them in a `Dictionary` with Char as a key and Integer as a value.  Then you could do something like this:

```
Dim letterValues As New Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)

letterValues.Add("S", 2)
letterValues.Add("U", 3)
letterValues.Add("M", 5)
' You can add every letter with its predefined value this way

Dim text As String = textbox1.Text
Dim sum As Integer = 0

For Each c As Char in text
    sum += letterValues(c)
Next
```

The result will be 10.

Comment: i want to compute the text written in text uisng the predefined values insert above in the table

Comment: Are S, U and M the only ones that have predefined values?  Or do other letters have predefined values as well?